# How do I filter a user input to accept char and int, but not specialchar. Then only takes the int into an array

Tags: java, input, user-input

Create a new queue with the String data type, wherein the user inputs the elements of the queue.

Restrictions:

1. The user can only input letters and numbers (A-Z, a-z & 0-9)
2. The program only takes the numbers from the input (integer)
3. In any instance that at least one special character is entered, the program will return an error. (this includes SPACE)

This is the requirement for the program.
And this is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This is a Queue program. Please enter how many integer/s will be inputted.");
        int count = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the valid interger/s:");
        String[] list = new String[count];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            list[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        Queue<String> newlist = new LinkedList<>();
        
        
        for (String i:list){
            newlist.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(newlist);
        
        Iterator<String> i=newlist.iterator();
        
            while(i.hasNext()){
                
                if(i.next().toString().matches("[^0-9]+")){
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        System.out.println(newlist);
    }
}
```

Obviously this program only removes char without being combined with int. I tried to use the `replaceAll("[^\\d]", " ");` but I don't know how to make it work. Please help.

Comment: What's the output of your program?

Comment: The output should be an array with unfiltered elements, e.g. `[hello123, 456, nice, hi789hey]` and an array which is then filtered to only take int, e.g. `[123, 456, 789]`. Also, the program should send an error when a special character has been inputted.

Answer (score 1):

The characters you allow are `A-Z`, `a-z`, and `0-9`.  In a regular expression `\\w` matches those characters.  And `\\W` matches **any but** those characters.  So set the latter to your delimiter and see how it works.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter("\\W+");
while (true) {
    System.out.println(scan.next());
}
```

Each group of characters returned from `scan.next()` should only contain your allowable characters.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this. But, once I have the allowed input, how do I remove the letters if it's inputted together with a number, e.g. `123hello` since the program should only take an int for the final array output.

Comment: white space will still be a delimiter and `scan.nextInt()` will also work.  So I presumed that when you wanted an `int` you would use `nextInt()` and when you wanted a string you would use `next()`.  Otherwise, this may not be useful for you.

Comment: Another option is to just take in strings normally (no delimiter set).  Then for each string you can use `match()` with a regular expression to see if it is just letters or just digits and process as required `(e.g. for an int, Integer.parseInt()`  But it pretty much doing the same thing as I previously suggested.

Comment: BTW, your prompt says *This is a Queue program. Please enter how many integer/s will be inputted?*.  Is that a mistake?  Are your inputs supposed to be integers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested first but I can't make it work, once I input something, the program doesn't stop to take more inputs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the program is designed to only take integers as an output, but only allows letters and numbers for an input. So, the user is intended to input integers, thus "_how many integer/s will be inputted?_".

Comment: Not certain what you are doing.  You need to use the for loop and your `count` to read in the values.  Doesn't it stop after that?   My example was just to demonstrate the delimiter.  Nothing else.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did but the input doesn't stop. I don't know what am I supposed to do.

Comment: OK. Edit your question and show for a given input what the expected output is (including your allowed characters).